# Как анимировать исчезновение react preloader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

возникла проблема, когда я делал искусственный прелоадер на сайте. Мне нужно чтобы через какое-то время он плавно скрывался, но я не могу понять как сделать плавное исчезновение компонента в React.
Я создал класс `.closed`, там `opacity: 0`, но это не помогло.
Код ниже, спасибо за помощь!

```
const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        }, 5000);
    });

    const content = loading ? <Preloader/> : <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    return (
        <div className='app'>
            {content}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться одной из библиотек анимации, на пример `'react-transition-group'`.
Вот пример похожего функционала:  https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-pasteur-m77l2vp00x?from-embed=&file=/index.js:165-189